# Android in app purchase security

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Ok, (to me) this is quite a complicated question which is making my noob brain hurt.

In my game, there are a series of special moves (combos). I intend for the majority of these to be in app purchases. Also, turning off ads will be an in app purchase.

It has been suggested to me that the player should also be able to earn combos through extended gameplay. Perhaps buy earning "credits" within the game that he can spend.

Either way, it seems to me, that the only way to store the fact that the combos are available to the player would be to store an indicator in the "shared preferences".

My concern is how vulnerable shared preferences is to user interference. As I understand it "shared preferences" is just a .xml file that's available to any root user. How is it possible to stop the user simply accessing the .xml and changing the data to "combo1 = true" or credits = "1,000,000" or "ads = off"?

As I'm writing this I've realised that instead of using an obvious word like "true" or "off", I could use codes that the user wouldn't be able to guess. Would that be secure?

But what about credits? How do you store a value that the user can't guess when the value can be anything.

I suppose I could proceed the value with a code that was derived from the value and an equation within the game code. So in the game there was an equation

code =((credits/2)*10)+1).

This would mean that if credits was 1000 then the value stored in sharedprefs would have to be 50011000. So unless the user knew the equation then they wouldn't be able to enter a valid value within the .xml

Do these ideas make sense? Would they work? Is there a better, more established way to do this?

Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: You could encrypt the data for these preferences, perhaps incorporating the current user ID (Google or your own) to stop the exchange of encrypted values?

Answer (score 0):

Use digital signatures or codes with a unique checksum algorithm which must validate to be accepted.

This changes the problem to reverse engineering your program to discover the key or disable the check.

Even that is not truly secure, but simply about making it harder.

Answer (score 0):

Share preferences to save data like this is not a good option at all. You should have remote service to do that coz if the user clears data from the setting all of his credits would be gone and even his purchase histroy. So please use remote server to save that data.